# How many fans can I control?

Tags: fan, cooling

I'm running a Phenom X6 on an ASUS M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3 motherboard. I just recently realized that I can quiet the otherwise noisy fan(s) with the ASUS Fan Xpert program they have. I'm loving it now since 50% fan speed changed it from noisy to almost silent.

Two questions

1. How do I know which fan(s) I'm slowing down? I have the CPU fan and 1 rear 120mm case fan, and I'm not sure which one's I'm slowing.
2. I was thinking of getting an Antec 1200 or Coolermaster 932 case with more room and more fans. How do I find out how many of those fans I can control with software? Does it slow them all down equally or can I pick and choose?

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

120mm fans tend to be quiet, so i'm guessing its the CPU fan. I'd check a few things - what's the 120mm fan connected to? if its a molex connector only then its prolly running at a fixed speed. CPU fans are definately motherboard controllable

Also many cases have their own fan speed selectors, or there's optional addons for that. Chances are though they won't be software controllable.

Comment: Yeah, the 120 is molex. So you're saying that the CPU was the loudest one and that's why it's so much quieter? Do you have any experience with Antec or Coolermaster? Are those 4 or 5 fans plugged into the mobo or the molex?

Comment: i have a coolermaster, but its got no extra fans. Most case fans seem to be molex powered from what i've seen though.

Comment: when you say it has no 'extra' fans, it does have the big 230mm fans on the front, side and top right? Can you control those with software?

Comment: no, it has none at all. like zero. Rule of thumb is the bigger the fans the quieter tho. In most cases, they are probably *not* motherboard controlled. there's either some controller in the case, or in a 5 1/2 inch bay, and these are really just potentiometers.

Comment: you have a coolermaster case with nothing but the CPU fan? what's the point of that?